# In Guitar Pro, how do I specify fret numbers for a chord?

Tags: guitar, chords, tablature, guitar-pro

I'm using the notation software Guitar Pro to create and edit tablature, and I can't figure out how to specify the fret number that a chord should be played on.  This is different than adding a capo to the track.  I want to specify, for example that the following E9 chord should be played across frets 6-7:

```
E9:3
```

How do I specify fret numbers in the chord builder in Guitar Pro?

Answer (score 2):

After some poking around I found the UI feature hidden in plain sight--a scroll bar to the right of the chord diagram.

To adjust the fret range, click and drag the scroll bar to the right of the chord diagram.

In Guitar Pro 7 the mouse scroll wheel can also be used.